# Get Element in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I work in typescript in angular 4 with template and associated class.

In my template HTML I have this code

```
<input class="search-input" mdInput placeholder="Enter" [mdAutocomplete]="mdauto" formControlName="mdac">
 <md-autocomplete #md="mdAutocomplete">
    ....
 </md-autocomplete>
```

In my typescript code I would like get the input with the formControlName = mdac but I don't know how to do ...

Do you have a idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
 <input class="search-input" mdInput placeholder="Enter" [mdAutocomplete]="mdauto" formControlName="mdac">
```

TS:

```
 form = new FormGroup({
        "mdac": new FormControl()
    });
get inputMdac(): AbstractControl { return this.form.get("mdac"); }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you read that?

[enter link description here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName)

In my opinion you have there everything you want.

Comment: in typescript mdac= new FormControl(); but I have this error Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined